# jMeter Embedded Resources Notification

Tags: java, jmeter

When I check "Retrieve All Embedded Resources from HTML Files" is there a way to get notified if any of those are 404s?

Right now we're using jMeter for a lot of front end testing in general, not just load testing so if it could notify us of broken images, css, etc.. that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Add a response assertion and check :

- Main and sub-samples

Sampler will be marked in error

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to edit ./bin/jmeter.properties and set httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true and uncomment to make it work.

Check [This site](https://performanceengineeringsite.wordpress.com/2018/07/01/ignore-embedded-resouces-as-error-in-jmeter/)